# Unexpected character '' (1:0) cardano-serialization-lib-browser

Tags: npm

Unexpected character '' (1:0)

File: node_modules@emurgo\cardano-serialization-lib-browser\cardano_serialization_lib_bg.wasm:1:0

error while running gatsby develop.

here is the [clone link](https://github.com/Berry-Pool/spacebudz)